# Git: ignore filename only in current directory

Tags: git, gitignore

I assumed that an entry:

```
./foo
```

in `bar/.gitignore` would ignore `bar/foo` but not `bar/hum/foo`. However, it doesn't ignore `bar/foo` at all. `foo` ignores both.

Comment: What does changing it to `/foo` do?

Comment: @evolutionxbox before testing it, according to my understanding of the documentation it would only ignore that file in the *root* directory. But I want to ignore it in a *sub-directory* (e.g. `bar`).

Comment: Then I'm a little confused of what you want here. Where do you want foo to be ignored?

Comment: in bar and bar only

Comment: Where is the `.gitignore` file?

Comment: In bar. Actually, now i'm testing it it seems that the `/` acts relative to the .gitignore file. The doc I was reading stated it was relative to the repository, but I'm pretty sure it works as I've described — can you confirm?

Comment: I can confirm — the paths in `.gitignore` are relative to the `.gitignore`, not repo root.